# Controlling the aspect ratio when DataRange values are different scales

Tags: plotting, labeling

## The Task

Create a `ListContourPlot` with custom data range and frame labels.

## Attempt at a Solution

First generate some data:

```
data = Table[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -2, 2, 0.1}, {y, -2, 2, 0.1}];
```

It seems I should use `DataRange` to set the range on the frame labels and `FrameLabel` to set the frame labels. This results in a picture that's way stretched out:

```
ListContourPlot[data,
    DataRange -> {{-150, 150}, {0, 1}},
    FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

## Observations

Either option on its own works just fine:

Plot it using just `DataRange`:

```
ListContourPlot[data,
      DataRange -> {{-150, 150}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

Plot it using just `FrameLabel`:

```
ListContourPlot[data,
      FrameLabel -> {"x","y"}]
```

[image]

Lastly, if I use `DataRange` parameters that are square, it also works:

```
ListContourPlot[data,
    DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
    FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

It's clear then that the issue arises from the fact that the `DataRange` values I want to use are not proportional. Surely there is a way around this.

Comment: Do you see this in a notebook or after exporting? What's your `$Version`? I don't reproduce your issue on v10.4.1 or v11.1 on Linux.

Comment: @corey979 Both. v11.1 on Linux. That is very strange.

Comment: I am on windows using V11.0 and I get all the plots have the same size independent of how I set `DataRange`.

Comment: All plots are the normal size for Version 11.1 in  Win 8.1 Pro.